# How to refer a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to add some results (images). I want to refer these images in other chapter(s) of the PDF so that the reader can just click the reference and go to the image directly. How I can do that?

Comment: Put your images in a `figure` environment, with `\label` and load the `hyperref` package. It should be loaded after all other packages, with some exceptions.

Comment: Or drop the `figure` environment and use the `\captionof{figure}{...}\label{...}` and `hyperref

Answer (score 7):

Here's the short way of doing it:

- Use `figure` environment, a `\caption` and a `\label`
- Or just use `\captionof{figure}{...}` and the label

But in both cases: No `\label`, no reference possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures



In \cref{fig:nonfloat} you see a non-floating image and in \cref{fig:float} it's floating around and causes troubles (most times)

\begingroup
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\captionof{figure}[No float duck]{I hate float environments and that's why I don't use and recommend them } \label{fig:nonfloat}
\endgroup

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption[And the dreadful floating one]{I hate float environments and that's why I don't use and recommend them but just to demonstrate their usage }
\label{fig:float}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\captionof` outside of a group is not advised, and you'll receive a warning to that effect.

Comment: @Werner: True, I added a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair around it